# Can't iterate over objects in a Java for...loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I can't add to my list this query:

```
// This query always return List<Object[]>
Query buscarRad = AreaPrincipal.em.createNamedQuery("Rad.buscarPorCuil");
buscarRad.setParameter("cuil", cuil);

List<Object[]> listaRad = buscarRad.getResultList();

int i = 0;
for (Object[] filaRad : listaRad) {
//  if (filaRad[i].equals(null)) {
    if (filaRad[i] != null) {
        lvRad.getItems().add(filaRad[i].toString());
    }
    i++;
    }
```

This is my vector listaRad:

[I need all values not null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3XxW.png)

...but my objects list break at first value and finalize. What's wrong?

Comment: `filaRad[i] != null` fails?

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: You are getting the first array in `listaRad` and checking the zero-eth element of that array, then you increment `i++`, then the for-loop is finished and goes on to the second array in listaRad (without having looked at any other elements in the first array) — you then check the _first_ (`i==1`) element of the _second_ array without looking at the zero-eth element or any subsequent element. Within your "for filaRad" _List_ loop you need another loop to look at all the _Array_ elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use nested loops to iterate over all rows, and then to iterate over all columns within each row. Try this:

```
for (Object[] filaRad : listaRad) { //for DB rows
    for (int i = 0; i < filaRad.length; i++) { //for DB columns within a row
        if (filaRad[i] != null) {
            lvRad.getItems().add(filaRad[i].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally you should put each column's value in an object's field rather than looping and converting them to `toString()`. Something like this:

```
List<MyDbRow> rows = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object[] filaRad : listaRad) {
    MyDbRow row = new MyDbRow();
    row.setId(fileRad[0]); //may require casting
    row.setName(fileRad[1]);

    rows.add(row);
}
```

Comment: @Kartik...thank you for your answer...very useful for me!

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. First you can put all elements at one level in an Object array list. After that you can loop through that list and check for null elements.

```
// This query always return List<Object[]>
Query buscarRad = AreaPrincipal.em.createNamedQuery("Rad.buscarPorCuil");
buscarRad.setParameter("cuil", cuil);

List<Object[]> listaRad = buscarRad.getResultList();
List<Object> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

int i = 0;
for (Object[] filaRad : listaRad) {
  finalList.add(Arrays.asList(filaRad));
}

for(Object o : finalList){
  if (o != null) {
        lvRad.getItems().add(o.toString());
  }
}

In java 8 you can do like this assuming that lvRad.getItems() is a list 
itself

lvRad.getItems().addAll(finalList.stream()
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Work's too! Thank's @muasif80